# Error serializing C# string using protobuf-net

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, protobuf-net

I would like to write a C# client to send a string via protobuf-net to a TCP server (implemented).  However, when I try to serialize the string using protobuf-net, I'm getting a `TypeInitializerException` "The type initializer for 'Singleton' threw an exception."

Here is the code:

```
public static void TelnetConnect(string host, int port) {
    ...
    Message msg = new Message("This is a test.");
    byte[] sentbytes = msg.Serialize();
    ...
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class MessageI {
    public byte[] Serialize() {
        byte[] result;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, this);  //THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
            result = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Message : MessageI {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string str { get; set; }

    public Message(string s) {
        this.str = s;
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of approaches advised by this site and others, without success.  I'm using C# on Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks, I very much appreciate your help.

UPDATE: The stack trace is:

```
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.get_Default()
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance)
   at PingNorbertServer.MessageI.Serialize() in C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PingNorbertServer\PingNorbertServer\NorbertClient.cs:line 37
   at PingNorbertServer.NorbertClient.TelnetConnect(String host, Int32 port) in C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PingNorbertServer\PingNorbertServer\NorbertClient.cs:line 23
   at PingNorbertServer.NorbertClient.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\RS88517\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PingNorbertServer\PingNorbertServer\NorbertClient.cs:line 14
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I don't know what the Singleton class is but it would probably be MemoryStream, Serializer or Message.

Comment: This exception usually occurs when a static constructor is called that throws an error.  Your debugger won't automatically take you in to the static constructor (presumable of "Singleton") so you need to look at the stack trace to find the real error

Comment: thanks, up 1.  what is the error though?

Comment: Please `catch` the exception and look at the `.InnerException`; the `.InnerException` will tell you what went boom, and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it erroring; your code, copied directly, works fine:

```
static void Main()
{
    var data = new Message("abc").Serialize();
}
```

But, to try to help:

- first, `catch` the `Exception`, and look at the `.InnerException`. More information is available for most exceptions; for example:

  ```
  try {
      // HERE: the code that errors
  } catch(Exception ex) {
      while(ex != null) {
          Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          ex = ex.InnerException;
      }
      throw;
  }
  ```
- secondly, note that a common issue with inheritance models is not *declaring* the inheritance - look at whether perhaps the base class needs decorating, for example:

  ```
  [ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Message))]
  ```
- another observation is the lack of a public parameterless constructor; now, protobuf-net doesn't *insist* on that (and indeed, it looks like it is treating the code in the question as an "auto tuple", and using the constructor that exists), but you can also either provide an additional (possibly non-public) parameterless constructor:

  ```
  private Message() {}
  ```

  or tell it to skip the constructor completely:

  ```
  [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
  ```

But: without knowing what the exception message is, it is hard to speculate further than this.

Comment: Thanks and +1.  Adding that try/catch helped and the error was that I needed a "IKVM.Reflection" reference in the project.  I'm now at "Error: Specified method is not supported" thrown on the same line.

Comment: @La woah! Stop! You should never ever need that. I wonder if you've referenced the wrong dll. IKVM is used only by the precompiler. If you can show code that somehow depends on IKVM then I need to fix that ASAP. But I think you've referenced the dll from the precompiler. Don't do that; it is different.

Comment: What do you mean by referencing the wrong dll?  What should I reference?  By the way, I removed the reference to IKVM in my program and still got the error "Specified method is not supported."

Comment: The other dll I had added is "protobuf-net.dll".

Comment: @La I'm assuming you are using the gcode bundle. That contains folders like full/net30 (which would be a great default) and others. See "what files do I need.txt"

Comment: where is "what files do I need.txt"?  I don't know what gcode is and to be honest, although I know other languages well I'm not so familiar with C#.

Comment: Google-code aka Code.Google.com - probably where you downloaded a zip file with lots of folders in it. The text file is in the root of the zip.

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure I downloaded it from Google.  Going there now.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the feedback.  The problem was that I had the wrong protobuf version, and error fixed.  Check mark for you.